# Converting PHP DateInterval to period specification

Tags: php

Using PHP, I want to be able to go from a `strtotime` [relative time](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) to a datetime interval that can be used for an iCalendar duration.

An example would be something like:

```
$date = \DateInterval::createFromString('5 minutes');
$period = $date->doSomeMagic();
echo $period; // should echo "PT5M"
```

Are there any built-in PHP functions to do this?  Or if there aren't, is there a library that can do it?

Comment: I'd hope that the magic would give `PT5M` for 5 minutes; because `P5M` is 5 months

Comment: @MarkBaker - ha, thanks -- corrected it :) A perfect example of why I want it in strtotime format rather than the period one ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [something like this](https://3v4l.org/qrii7)

```
$date = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('2 days 5 minutes');

function doSomeMagic(\DateInterval $date) {
    $interval = 'P' .
        ($date->y == 0 ? null : $date->y . 'Y') .
        ($date->m == 0 ? null : $date->m . 'M') .
        ($date->d == 0 ? null : $date->d . 'D');
    $timeInterval =
        ($date->h == 0 ? null : $date->h . 'H') .
        ($date->i == 0 ? null : $date->i . 'M') .
        ($date->s == 0 ? null : $date->y . 'S');
    return $interval . ((!empty($timeInterval)) ? 'T' . $timeInterval : null);
}


$period = doSomeMagic($date);
echo $period;
```